# tikz - flatten/flush line with rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, line, anchor

I drew the following picture below.

To extend squares, I attached lines at the corner angles, i.ex node.45. It can hardly be seen, but they are are not exacly in one line.
How is it possible to flush/flatten the rectangle with the lines? Is there an easy way?
The squared rectangles are custom made nodes, where I copied the code.

[image: tikz picture]

I used the following operations:

```
\node[square, draw, anchor = west, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2.6em] (w) at (v.east) {$s_{t-3}$};
\draw (w.45) -- ++  (2.6em,0em);
```

Thanks for tips

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE :) // Unfortunately we can only help you, if you add your preamble etc., which is relevant to your problem. S.th. we can copy and run. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated but you use `square` (which is not defined natively) for your nodes and then use different minimum width and height. If you absolutely want squares, you may use `regular polygon` from the `shapes.geometric` library. 
Then, please show us what you have already done if you want to get some real help on that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of `chains`, `fit` and `positioning` libraries:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm,
  start chain = going right,
     M/.style = {minimum size=11mm, on chain},
     N/.style = {M, draw, inner sep=0mm, fit=#1},
   FIT/.style = {draw, thick, inner sep=0mm, fit=#1},
                        ]
\foreach \i [count=\j] 
            in {s_t,s_{t-1},s_{t-2},s_{t-3}, ,\dotsm, ,
                s_{t-k},s_{t-1},s_{t-2},s_{t-3}, ,\dotsm, ,s_{t-k}} 
\node (m\j) [M] {$\i$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4,8,9,10,11,15}
\node       [N=(m\i)] {};

\node   [FIT=(m1) (m15)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]